# How to import unicode data from csv file to database using pygrametl?

Tags: database, unicode, pygrametl

when I try to import data in Thai Language inside the Data Warehouse in PostgreSQL using the following code in pygrametl:

```
inputdata = CSVSource(open(file_name, 'r', encoding="utf8"), delimiter=',')

for row in inputdata:

    row['text'] = pygrametl.getstr(row['text']).encode("utf-8")

    facttbl.insert(row)
```

it works but it adds 'b' into the text. if I remove the encode("utf-8") part, then it gives me the error:

"missing value for column text"

If I change the text to English, then without adding encode("utf-8") it works. The error only shows up if I have some unicode characters inside the csv file I am reading from.

Comment: Without knowing pygrametl, I'm convinced there is a way to work with arbitrary Unicode data. However, it's hard to know what is going wrong without seeing what you are doing. Can you show some code that somebody else can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I use this code to enter data in Thai Language inside the data warehouse: row['text'] = pygrametl.getstr(row['text']).encode("utf-8"), it works but it adds 'b' in to the text. if I remove the encode("utf-8") part, then it gives me the error "missing value for column text"

Comment: Please put together a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit it into the question. This will allow anybody to quickly try what you tried. I think that the problem might not be connected to this single line of code only.